# Encoding error on updating custom_enum[] column while updating. Cannot encode parameter of type java.util.ArrayList ([TYPE1])))

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

Insertion part is working properly but when I update custom enum set column, this exception is thrown

> java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext(1)" failed (expected: onNext(1); actual: onError(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot encode parameter of type java.util.ArrayList ([TYPE1])))

**DB Config**

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DatabaseConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {
  ... missing code
  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    PostgresqlConnectionFactory postgresqlConnectionFactory = new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(
      PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration
        .builder()
         ... missing code
        .codecRegistrar(
          EnumCodec
            .builder()
            .withEnum("interface_type", InterfaceType.class)
            .build()
        )
        .build()
    );
    ... missing code
  }

  @Override
  protected List<Object> getCustomConverters() {
    return List.of(
      new InterfaceTypeWriter()
    );
  }
}
```

**Converter**

```
@WritingConverter
public class InterfaceTypeWriter extends EnumWriteSupport<InterfaceType> {}
```

**Domain object**

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;

@Table
public class DomainObject {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @Column("interface_types")
  private Set<InterfaceType> interfaceTypes; //InterfaceType is a custom enum
}
```

**Dao service**

```
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.R2dbcEntityTemplate;

@Service
public class Dao {

  private final R2dbcEntityTemplate template;
  public Mono<Long> update(Long id, DomainObject object) {
    Update update = Update
      .update("interface_types", object.getInterfaceTypes());

    Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
    return template.update(query, update, DomainObject.class);
  }
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    interface_types interface_type[]
);
```